QLED LCD pannel with green pixels
I have this QLED LCD panel with these strange green matrix like stripes. This picture is of the bottom where the CoFs are placed and it's where the LED strip is situated. I disconnected everything (motherboard, gate driver boards) so the LCD panel is not getting any power in this setup only the backlight is on.
I was wondering what causes these green pixels eventhough the panel is disconnected from the power. Is it some sort of coupling or leakage from the LEDs? Are these pixels stuck? Is it causes by the heat of the LED strip?


If the panel isn't being driven / refreshed, then the pixels will be in an "undefined" state. Do you have these artifact when the panel is operating normally? (with an image on screen)

@Attie if the panel is operating normally, the pixels become black but there still is a very faint remnant of these green pixels

How old is the panel?  Could it have suffered burnin?

@BenVoigt QLED 50Q64T from 2020
